# Can not upgrade numpy-1.2.1 on Mac os

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, python-2.6

I am frustrated in problem with numpy..

I need to install matplotlib and it requires numpy, I can easy install only 1.2.1 after trying to upgrade I have a tones of errors, so here pip.log: http://pastebin.com/wNwCgttP

any idea how I can install numpy 1.4 or later? May be problem in any dependences?

I have preinstalled python 2.6.1 on Mac os x 10.6.8

Answer (score 0):

Try downloading a `dmg` file from [sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/numpy/files/NumPy/1.7.0/). That should allow you to install a newer version of `numpy`.
You can do the same for `matplotlib`, getting a `dmg` file from [the matplotlib website](http://matplotlib.org/downloads.html)
Additionally, you can get newer versions of PYTHON as `dmg` files from the [python website](http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.7.5/)